# What to do with questions that don't show any research effort?

Tags: discussion

I apologize in advance as this is probably a common question, I did a quick search but couldn't find a satisfying answer.

So there's a category of poor questions which don't show any research effort whatsoever, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41616042/addition-keys-in-json). To me they're just a "plz give me teh code" kind of question.

My question is, what are we supposed to do about it?

Maybe I downvote it and then leave a classic "What have you tried?" comment, or should I just vote for closing it?

Usually I try to close it, but I'm never sure whether it should be off-topic, unclear or other.

Also, I remember few years ago there used to be another reason for closing which was along the lines of "the question shows no research effort". What happened to it?

Comment: The irony of not doing your research when asking this question is rather thick here.

Comment: Read the tooltip when you hover over the downvote arrow, it tells you exactly what to do.

Comment: "No research" is not really an argument. We *do not know* how much or little research OP did. For all we know they sat there the last 3 weeks banging their head against the wall… (Note, I'm not saying that question is a good question or anything, just that we cannot prove research time and hence it's no criterion.) For the same reason "what have you tried" comments are one of the least constructive comments you could leave.

Comment: @deceze Simone specifically asked what to do about question that don't *show* their research effort (as all of the SE guidelines also uses in its guidelines).

Comment: @deceze: which is why we require that a user *shares their research* in the question. Stating, like the OP did here, that 'they searched', does not qualify. When you searched *what did you find*. How did that fail to answer your question? etc.

Comment: Adding a sentence like "I have read the documentation but did not find any appropriate method" doesn't fundamentally change a question. That is decent *research effort*, if in fact the OP did read the proper  documentation, and there's nothing more they could "show" for it. – The real issue is if a question is *too broad*, because the OP hasn't narrowed it down enough through trial and error.

Comment: "there used to be another reason for closing which was along the lines of "the question shows no research effort"" We never had such a close reason. The closest one to that is "Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved" which is removed because the powers that be don't think thin-skinned people can learn how to accept criticism.

Comment: @deceze You're correct that *stating that you did research* is not useful to a question.  Actually *showing research* and describing how it failed to answer your question is, on the other hand, enormously useful.  That's why *stating that you did research* is not actually *showing research effort*.

Comment: @Servy I think "effort" is a contentious term and doesn't really hit the mark of what we're really looking for. *"Share information about your attempts to solve this problem which narrow down possible solutions"* is *really* what we're asking. Without that, a question can be either *unclear* or *too broad.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things you can do with a question that is poorly researched.

1. Downvote it. If you hover over the downvote button, you'll see the text "This question does not show any research effort..." so that's one of the primary reasons for downvoting.
2. Many poorly researched questions are just incomplete versions of questions that have already been asked and answered on Stack Overflow, so if you want to cast a close vote, you'll need to find a good, canonical, original question that covers the same ground and close it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

In this case :

- downvote
- close as :

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Unlike Bill The lizard, for something without any effort, I don't always do the effort to find the duplicate.

Comment: I don't like to use this one unless the OP is explicitly asking for debugging help, because it can be confusing. But I have to admit that if we removed that bit and changed the close description to "Questions must include the desired behavior..." it would fit perfectly. Unfortunately, not every question has to include code, so that wouldn't make a good general-purpose close reason.

Comment: @BilltheLizard as i said that was for that case. And well I just don't want to give the answer to someone by linking a duplicate when he is just "plz give me the code"

Comment: Yeah, I can see using it in some cases where the OP has truly shown zero effort, since it does give a nice description of the kinds of questions we're looking for.

Comment: I tend to abuse "too broad" for this, since any answer would need to be basically a complete tutorial and therefore "too broad". Less confusing than the close reason you suggested, unless they actually are asking for debugging help.